# Selenium Webdriver + Jmeter + StormRunner for Performance test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, stormrunner-load

I wanted to try out integration of Selenium Jmeter and StormRunner. My end goal is to do Load testing with 'n' number of users on StormRunner
What ? - For e.g. I have Selenium Script, convert it in to Jmeter (I can get this information from many sources)
Then my Jmeter script should get ready
Then upload Jmeter script in to StormRunner and pass the necessary parameter through Jenkins and run the load test.

I really want the opinion here about feasibility and whether it is in right direction or not.
Idea here is that Automated Load/Performance test

Comment: Could you please post about your objective of your performance testing, application stack, load details etc?

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is a **browser** automation framework and JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) so your "Automated" requirement might not be fulfilled especially if your tests are relying on client-side checks like sorting or waiting for element to appear.

Theoretically [given you properly configure JMeter it can behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), but it still not be executing client-side JavaScript.

If you're fine with this constraint - your approach is valid, if not and the "automated functional test" requirement is the must - consider migrating to [TruClient Protocol](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/p_truclient_protocol.htm) instead

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you covert your script to a native Loadrunner/Stormrunner form of virtual user?

You should look at the value of what you are trying to achieve.  The end value of a performance test is in analysis.  Analysis simply takes the timing records and the resource measurements produced during the test, bringing them together on a common timestamp, and then allowing you to analyze what resource "X" is being impinged when timing record "Y" is too long.   This then points to some configuration or code which locks up on resource, "X."

What is your path to value in your model?  You speak about converting a functional test script to a performance one.  Realistically, you should already know that your code, "works for one," before you get to asking, "Does it work for many?"  There is a change in script definitions which typically accompanies this understanding.

Where are your collection of resources noted?  Which Resources?  On which Hosts?   This is on the "path to value" problem where you need to have the resource measurements to diagnose root cause of poor performance.